# Trying to output a bubble sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm attempting to bubble sort an array, then output the original and the sorted. It seems to work, but when it outputs the data, it outputs [l@486f03ec as both arrays instead of numbers. I don't know what I did wrong. My code is

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Gates_sortingBubble{

public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Please enter five numbers.", "Sorting Arrays", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

  String number1s;
  number1s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Number 1: ");
  int number1 = Integer.parseInt(number1s);

  String number2s;
  number2s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Number 2: ");
  int number2 = Integer.parseInt(number2s);

  String number3s;
  number3s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Number 3: ");
  int number3 = Integer.parseInt(number3s);

  String number4s;
  number4s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Number 4: ");
  int number4 = Integer.parseInt(number4s);

  String number5s;
  number5s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Number 5: ");
  int number5 = Integer.parseInt(number5s);

  int[] numbers = {number1, number2, number3, number4, number5};

  sort(numbers);

 }

 public static void sort(int[] tosort){

  int[] original = tosort;

  int j;
  boolean flag = true;
  int temp;

  while(flag){       
     flag= false;  
     for( j=0;  j < tosort.length -1;  j++ ){
        if ( tosort[ j ] < tosort[j+1] ){   // change to > for ascending sort
           temp = tosort[ j ];              
           tosort[ j ] = tosort[ j+1 ];
           tosort[ j+1 ] = temp;
           flag = true;  
        }
     }
  } 

  print(tosort, original);
}   


public static void print(int[] sorted, int[] unsorted){

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Your original five numbers are: [" + unsorted + "]. \nYour new five numbers are: [" + sorted + "].", "Sorted Arrays", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

}


}
```

Comment: Check out `Object#toString()` and how it applies to array types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Arrays.toString(sorted)` in the `print` method to get the desired behaviour.

> public static String toString(int[] a)
>
> Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array. The string representation consists of a list of the array's elements, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (a comma followed by a space). Elements are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(int). Returns "null" if a is null.
>
> Parameters:
>       a - the array whose string representation to return
>
> Returns:
>       a string representation of a
>
> Since:
>       1.5

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Arrays.toString` in `java.util`.